# How to turn a span without content into a divider line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying  to turn the following span tags into horizontal dividers:

```
HTML:

<div class="form-group-divider">
  <span></span>
  <h5>{{ field.title }}</h5>
  <span></span>
</div>

CSS:

.form-group-divider {
  h5 {
    display: inline-block
  }

  span {
    background-color: border-color
    width: 100%
    height: 1px
    content: ' '
  }
}
```

The span tags don't display if the they have content. I thought `content: ' '` would fix that problem but it didn't.

How to make these span tags display?

Comment: Are you using a CSS preprocessor? The CSS you have provided is not valid.  `content` only works with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: `<hr/>`???????!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>` are inline elements, therefore you need content to give it any discernable dimensions. I added `display:block` since they are supposed to behave like a `<hr/>`. BTW, why don't you use `<hr/>`? The following demo has an example of `<hr/>` and `<span>`

### Demo

```css
.form-group-divider h5 {
  display: inline-block
}

.form-group-divider span {
  display: block;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group-divider">
  <hr/>
  <h5>Using &lt;hr/&gt;</h5>
  <hr/>
</div>


<div class="form-group-divider">
  <span></span>
  <h5>Using &lt;span&gt;</h5>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Because I need the span h5 and span tags to be horizontally aligned. I think I can do that with the hr tags.

Comment: Take a look at [Simple Styles for <hr>'s - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/) Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css
span::after {

```
content: '';
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`display: block`

HTML:

```
  <div class="form-group-divider">
     <span></span>
        <h5>{{field.title}}</h5>
        <span></span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%
    height: 1px;
}
```